# Undentified shell script "open" added to open at login

Tags: terminal, bash, script, startup

Logged in into my laptop this morning, to see that a shell script "open" has been added to open at login. Its from an unidentified developer, created a month back, but just got added to startup tasks. Here is the screenshot
[image]

Found the shell script at bin.
[image]

Unfortunately, it is not possible to gather much info about this, because the encoding seems to be different.

[image]

Can someone tell me what this is for? Or should I reset my laptop due to potential malware? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a shell script but a binary, and it's (as anything in `/usr/bin`) part of macOS. Did you install any specific software prior to this showing up in "open at login"? If you don't remember, you can also disable it in Settings and reboot to see whether there is a difference.

Comment: I just installed the drivers for a 3DConnexions Space Mouse and it added `open` to my startup items. (It also wanted permission to modify certificate settings, which I refused)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't recognize an entry on *open at login* in settings, it is safe to remove it by selecting and clicking the **-** at the bottom left.

[image: open at login]

The `open` command is used to open macOS applications. You can reboot the system and see if any applications load on start.